# How to extract the first column that appears when a dataframe is printed in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame named dat.ann as given below:

```
             Gender Age
GSM27015      M  26
GSM27016      M  26
GSM27018      M  29
GSM27021      M  37
GSM27023      M  40
GSM27024      M  42
GSM27025      M  45
GSM27017      F  27
GSM27019      F  30
GSM27020      F  36
GSM27022      F  38
GSM27026      F  48
```

I want to extract just the first column into a vector, which is not named, although if I see it under Excel it is named as ID. Anyway, I tried to extract it as dat.ann.id<-dat.ann[,1]. This puts the gender values in dat.ann.id. Then I tried, dat.ann.id<-dat.ann[,0]. But this puts a null value. Please let me know how to extract the first column.

Thanks

Comment: `rownames(dat.ann)`

Comment: @thelatemail maybe you should transform your comment to an answer...